# webpack babel-loader cache issue

Tags: javascript, caching, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm running my first webpack project with [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader).

My problem is that every time i recompile i have to delete manually the output files in order to let the browers see the new ones

is this a cache issue or something? This is my `webpack.config.js`

```
 test: /\.js$/,
     use: [
         {
             loader: 'babel-loader',
             options: {
                 presets: ['es2015']
             }
         }
     ]
```

and my start script:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode=development",
  },
```

Comment: What does your start script look like? Depends on the parameters that you have provided there

Comment: @SaranshKataria that's my start script `webpack --mode=development`

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your http server. What are you using to serve the output files?

Comment: @CodingIntrigue i think u'r right, i tested with a static html file and it reloads correctly. i'm using Tomcat as web server, but can't understand how to fix it